# How to avoid creating duplicates when two rules match the same emails

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have amongst my Outlook rules :

- a rule #1 that move some messages to a folder A
- a rule #2 that move some messages to a folder B

When an email matches both, one copy goes to folder A, the other to folder B.

I would like everything to go to folder A and nothing to folder B.
Because rule #1 is higher in the list and rule #2 is lower, and Outlook says it applies rules sequentially, I thought this would be the case.

I have outlook 2007 on Windows XP SP3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're editing Rule A, when you're at the select action(s) pane, select "stop processing more rules"

So if Rule A matches, it won't end up doing Rule B

Additionally, in the 'Email Rules' window, make sure that the Rule A rules are before Rule B in the list (you can change the order with the up and down arrows in that windows toolbar)